# How to send message in muc group using ejabberd API?

Tags: ejabberd, ejabberd-api

I know using " ejabberdctl send_message groupchat user1@localhost room1@conference.localhost Sub Bodyyy" this command we can send group messages. But how to implement the same using HTTP API that ejabbered provides ([here](https://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/ejabberd-api/admin-api))? Is it possible? Else what are the other options which i can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, see https://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/ejabberd-api/simple-configuration/ to enable the module. Or you can enable ejabberd_xmlrpc and send XML-RPC queries.

Comment: Thanks, I saw them. I have enabled HTPP module I am just asking for the API that sends a group message. But on the whole there no HTTP API that I can request from postman to send group messages ... Right?

Comment: Right, there is no specific command to send message to a room.